# What am I missing in my third JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

#### INTRO:

Providing a little context: I am trying to create workaround solutions in a HTML/CSS/JS based webticket builder.

This means I am creating online forms with a drag and drop tool that automatically generates titles, names, ids and all that in the general HTML code. So what I can't do is change the overall set up.

Every selection field I create though gives me a small textfield which is supposed to be used as a help field for this particular selection field. So for example I have a text field "mail adress" - the help text would then show "please use the format firstname.lastname@mailprovider.com" underneath it.

This "help" textbox is plain HTML, providing me with the possibility to add extra code inbetween - hence it's everything but pretty.

the html layout is not my idea, and I can only partially change it.

#### What I want to do:

Create an extra list with empty links, so I can use "onclick" on each item:

```
<!-- automatically visible -->

<!-- Checkbox im Status checked -->
<input type="checkbox" id="check" onclick="toggleBoxVisibility()" checked> Please choose which assignment type is to be requested:

<!-- Modal / Pop Up Fenster -->
<div id="mymodal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">


      <!-- List items as links to make them clickable -->
        <ul id="myUL">
        <font size="3em">
          <li><a id="li1" title="item1" href="#" onclick="returncontent(this);return false;showitem1();">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a id="li2" title="item2" href="#" onclick="returncontent(this);return false;showitem2();">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a id="li3" title="item3" href="#" onclick="returncontent(this);return false;showitem3();">Item 3</a></li>
        </font>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

The selection list then has 3 triggering functions:
1. returning the selected item to another textfield (works)
2. not opening a "#" site (works)
3. show further selection fields based on the selected list item (does not work)

This is basically an attempt to create a dynamic webform, as the tool itself doesn't provide such options

So this is what I additionally have:
 - a fieldset with class "item1" and two textfields:

This code is copied directly from the tool, hence the intuitive ids and layout in general.

```
<fieldset class="item1"><legend>Item 1 Selections</legend><div id="d_000000001845952" class="field  text"><label for="f_000000001845952" id="l_000000001845952">Information 1</label>
                        <input id="f_000000001845952" name="id23" value=""     />
                      </div><div id="d_000000001844977" class="field  text "><label for="f_000000001844977" id="l_000000001844977">Information 2</label>
                      <input id="f_000000001844977" name="id24" value=""     /></div></fieldset>
```

- a CSS code hiding the fieldset "item1" when the webform is opened:

```
  .item1 {
         display: none;
       }
```

- and my js functions:
  The first to return selected item to a specific textfield:

```
   <script type = "text/JavaScript">
   function returncontent(elem) {
   document.getElementById("f_000000001845521").value=elem.title;
   document.getElementById("mymodal").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("check").checked = false;
   }
   returncontent();
   </script>
```

And the second to show me the necessary selection fields for list item 1:

```
<script type = "text/JavaScript">
function showitem1() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("item1")[0].style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

And now the latter is, what doesn't work and I don't understand why.

I have build several checkboxes that display/hide individual fields and fieldsets via ID or class so for my understanding I didn't do anything different this time except triggering two functions at once.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/e6d38bwy/) you can find a fiddle of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why you do it, but your problem will be solved by changing the order of functions in your **onclick**. I changed the place of **return false;** after **showitem1()**

[Check workable version here](https://jsfiddle.net/wrmp6on9/)

```html
    <ul id="myUL">
      <font size="3em">
        <li><a id="li1" title="item1" href="#" onclick="returncontent(this);showitem1();return false;">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a id="li2" title="item2" href="#" onclick="returncontent(this);showitem2();return false;">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a id="li3" title="item3" href="#" onclick="returncontent(this);showitem3();return false;">Item 3</a></li>
      </font>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Ah jesus.... It always ends up being something very stupid. Thank you! After hours of searching for missing semicolons and the like and did not look at the order of the functions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("f_000000001845521").readOnly = true;

function toggleBoxVisibility() {
    if (document.getElementById("check").checked == true) {
        document.getElementById("mymodal").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("mymodal").style.display = "none";
    }
}
toggleBoxVisibility();

function returncontent(elem) {
    if(elem)
    document.getElementById("f_000000001845521").value = elem.title;
    document.getElementById("mymodal").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("check").checked = false;
}
returncontent();

function showitem1() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("item1")[0].style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.item1 {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="f_000000001845521" name="id12" value="This field is set automatically, based on chosen element from the list below." />
<div class="help">
   <script type="text/JavaScript">
         document.getElementById("f_000000001845521").readOnly = true;
   </script>
</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="check" onclick="toggleBoxVisibility()" checked> Please choose which assignment type is to be requested:
<div id="mymodal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <ul id="myUL">
            <font size="3em">
                <li><a id="li1" title="item1" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="returncontent(this);showitem1();">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a id="li2" title="item2" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="returncontent(this);showitem2();">Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a id="li3" title="item3" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="returncontent(this);showitem3();">Item 3</a></li>
            </font>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<fieldset class="item1">
    <legend>Item 1 Selections</legend>
    <div id="d_000000001845952" class="field  text"><label for="f_000000001845952" id="l_000000001845952">Information 1</label>
        <input id="f_000000001845952" name="id23" value="" />
    </div>
    <div id="d_000000001844977" class="field  text "><label for="f_000000001844977" id="l_000000001844977">Information 2</label>
        <input id="f_000000001844977" name="id24" value="" /></div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Ah okay perfect, adding the `href="javascript:void(0)"` is a much prettier solution to the random workaround with the "return false" I found somewhere.Thank you! That also eliminates the problem caused by it.

Answer (score 0):

I've change a couple parts of your code here but the most notable is that you can call the first (almost global type of function) from the the second function. I did also combine the three `showitem` functions into one and set which `fieldset` to show based off the clicked elements title.

You can call each function from the `onclick`. You would simply need to change the order of `return false;`, placing it at the end (or just remove it and `return: false;` from the function!?!).

```js
function toggleBoxVisibility() {
  if (document.getElementById("check").checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("mymodal").style.display = "block";
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(els, function(el) {
      el.style.display = "none";
    });
 } else {
    document.getElementById("mymodal").style.display = "none";
  }
}
toggleBoxVisibility();

function returncontent(elem) {
  document.getElementById("f_000000001845521").value = elem.title;
  document.getElementById("mymodal").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("check").checked = false;
}

function showitem(elem) {
  returncontent(elem);
  document.getElementsByClassName(elem.title)[0].style.display = "block";
  return false;
}
```

```css
.item1,
.item2,
.item3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="f_000000001845521" name="id12" value="This field is set automatically, based on chosen element from the list below." />
<div class="help">
  <script type="text/JavaScript">
    document.getElementById("f_000000001845521").readOnly = true;
  </script>
</div>

<!-- automatically visible -->

<!-- Checkbox im Status checked -->
<input type="checkbox" id="check" onclick="toggleBoxVisibility()" checked> Please choose which assignment type is to be requested:

<!-- Modal / Pop Up Fenster -->
<div id="mymodal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <!-- List items as links to make them clickable -->
    <ul id="myUL">
      <font size="3em">
        <li><a id="li1" title="item1" href="#" onclick="showitem(this);">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a id="li2" title="item2" href="#" onclick="showitem(this);">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a id="li3" title="item3" href="#" onclick="showitem(this);">Item 3</a></li>
      </font>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<fieldset class="item item1">
  <legend>Item 1 Selections</legend>
  <div id="d_000000001845952" class="field  text">
    <label for="f_000000001845952" id="l_000000001845952">Information 1</label>
    <input id="f_000000001845952" name="id23" value="" />
  </div>
  <div id="d_000000001844977" class="field  text ">
    <label for="f_000000001844977" id="l_000000001844977">Information 2</label>
    <input id="f_000000001844977" name="id24" value="" />
  </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="item item2">
  <legend>Item 2 Selections</legend>
  <div id="d_000000001845952" class="field  text">
    <label for="f_000000001845952" id="l_000000001845952">Information 1</label>
    <input id="f_000000001845952" name="id23" value="" />
  </div>
  <div id="d_000000001844977" class="field  text ">
    <label for="f_000000001844977" id="l_000000001844977">Information 2</label>
    <input id="f_000000001844977" name="id24" value="" />
  </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="item item3">
  <legend>Item 3 Selections</legend>
  <div id="d_000000001845952" class="field  text">
    <label for="f_000000001845952" id="l_000000001845952">Information 1</label>
    <input id="f_000000001845952" name="id23" value="" />
  </div>
  <div id="d_000000001844977" class="field  text ">
    <label for="f_000000001844977" id="l_000000001844977">Information 2</label>
    <input id="f_000000001844977" name="id24" value="" />
  </div>
</fieldset>
```